# Using Entity Framework to insert multiple child objects while updating the parent

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I'm trying to keep track of changes to my Asset's properties via the setters in the Asset, which is working.

I then pass this Asset along with its changes:

```
(Business) Asset
   - public string Name...
   - public DateTime ChangedDate...
   -List<ChangeLogs>
```

to a method and I'm using AutoMapper to convert it along with its children to an (EntityFramework) Asset; this is working as well.

In my method I

```
using(var dbContext = new DBContext())
{

   // Map our (Business)Asset to our (Entity Framework)Asset
   var dataAsset = Mapper.Map<Business.Asset, Data.Asset>(asset);

   dbContext.Assets.Attach(asset);

   dbCore.SaveChanges();
}
```

I'm getting this error on the Attach line:

> An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager.
>   The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same
>   key.

The believe the key its referring to is my ChangeLog Id (PK).

Is there a way to add multiple ChangeLogs to my Asset and then save it?

Comment: If you are trying to add ChangeLogs, wouldn't you just add it directly instead of using Assets? i.e. dbContext.ChangeLogs.Add(changelog); Of course you would have to manually insert the asset id in your changelog object before attaching.

Comment: I tried as you suggested and it failed on the SaveChanges().

Message=Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.
  Source=EntityFramework
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
       at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()

Comment: I've experienced such an error previously when a required field has a null value. Before you add the ChangeLog, have you made sure that all required fields contain data?

Answer (score 0):

When you have a detached entity and try to attach it back that already exists in the context, you will get this exception.

To resolve this, try to load the old entity and save the changes from the new entity.

```
using(var dbContext = new DBContext())
{
   // Map our (Business)Asset to our (Entity Framework)Asset
   var dataAsset = Mapper.Map<Business.Asset, Data.Asset>(asset);
   var oldEntity = dbContext.Assets.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == dataAsset.Id);
   dbContext.Entry(oldEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(dataAsset);
   dbContext.Entry(oldEntity.ChangeLogs).CurrentValues.SetValues(dataAsset.ChangeLogs);

   dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Ganesh, using what you suggested saves my Asset but it doesn't save the ChangeLogs.

Comment: How about if you add bContext.Entry(oldEntity.ChangeLogs).CurrentValues.SetValues(dataAsset.ChangeLogs); before the SaveChanges call?

Comment: I eventually got this to work but I was still having some issues with to many records getting inserted into the DB. Once I added an Ignore line to my Mapper everything started to work. Thanks.